# The word noggin

Tags: phrases, expressions

Where did the word "noggin" originate? My daughter was talking to her friend and the expression "your noggin" was used. Then one had asked the other, "where did that phrase come from originally?"

Comment: See answer here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/9407/114389

Comment: @DogLover That answer is spot-on, in my opinion. I have only ever heard *noggin* used for a drink - *a noggin of ale*. But then my origins are in Norfolk, and I was interested to see that that is where it comes from. But it was interesting to see the further comment from Mick to the effect that it is related to German mugs in the shape of a head - probably where the idea of *noggin = head* came from. Though I've never heard that. Sounds uniquely American to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a strange sounding word, but 'noggin' refers to one's head. 
To simplify, "She fell of the cart and got a huge bump on her noggin."

Apparently, it was first used sometime in the first half of the 17th century. But it probably didn't mean 'head' then. This meaning came about much later in the 1880s. The earliest usage in literature that I remember was in 'Bud, Not Buddy'.